# check if /dev/input/eventX obey Multi-touch protocol or single-touch protocol

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I want to write some touch input events to rooted android device using sendevent.
But some android devices obey Multi-touch protocol, the other obey single-touch protocol,just like [multi-touch-protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt) say.
Is there any way to check if /dev/input/eventX obey Multi-touch protocol or single-touch protocol programly?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check for multi-touch support is to already know the device name, or to listen for multi-touch events.

Comment: I've thought about this idea too. What I was worried about is if this method suits the most mobile devices.I'll try your idea.